# Avoid showing Microsoft authentication screen for Intune SDK integrated iOS application

Tags: ios, intune

I have integrated Microsoft Intune SDK in iOS application. Able to perform all operation mainly sharing files from Outlook to my application.

I installed my application, outlook,etc on fresh device from company portal. When I share any file from Outlook to My application it shows Microsoft login screen only once as below:
[image]

It ask for login credential only once at first time share file.

I don't want to show Microsoft login screen, it must automatically authenticate using broker app like Company portal, outlook, etc.
As per [Intune documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-ios#configure-settings-for-the-intune-app-sdk), I have already added configuration in iOS info.plist i.e. "AutoEnrollOnLaunch" to true.

How do I completely avoid showing MS login screen?

Comment: Has the user already completed a Microsoft login in your app?  Refer to the following note on auto enrolment *Notes: If no managed identity is found or no valid token for the identity is available in the MSAL cache, the enrollment attempt will silently fail without prompting for credentials, unless the app has also set MAMPolicyRequired to YES.*. You cannot completely avoid showing the Microsoft login. The user must complete it once to activate the app enrolment.

Comment: No, user has not done Microsoft login in my app. In application we have not set "MAMPolicyRequired", so default is NO. As broker app like company portal, MS outlook, etc has already enrolled user, my app should enrol silently using broker app, right?

Comment: No, because your app does not have an identity available in the MSAL cache. MSAL can share credentials between *your apps* because your apps can have a shared keychain via an application group.  MSAL in your app cannot access an identity from, say, Outlook because you and Microsoft are different developers.  Once you tap OK on the dialog in your screenshot then MSAL should open the authenticator, complete a brokered auth and then return to your app.

Comment: But if identity is not available in MSAL cache, how it automatically detect email address?  The same email address is present in Outlook and Company portal app. As per screenshot it only ask for password. if MSAL cache is sharing email address then it should silently login as well, correct?

Comment: I guess *no valid token for the identity is available in the MSAL cache*